# Screen size and density support android

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-screen-support, android-screen

I know that we should use Configuration qualifiers for our resources.We should put bitmaps according to screen density(ldpi,mdpi,hdpi etc.)...My question is should we use same drawables for different screen sizes.Suppose a device is 3 inches(normal screen size) and another is 5 inches(large size) BUT BOTH ARE MDPI, So is it a better practice to put drawble in drawable-mdpi folder or shall we use drawable-mdpi and drawable-large-mdpi folders respectively

Answer (score 3):

I recommend to read the guidelines about using resources for different screen sizes:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

It depends on what exactly You want to do. If You have some complicated layouts with much graphics, that must be changed for different sizes, follow the guideline.

Comment: I have already read it and understood it....Was just asking to know which was abetter thing and I do have a  complicated layout so maybe i would use two different qualifiers

Comment: I know it is much work, but believe me, You will have more success by selling Your apps....

Answer (score 1):

use different drawable for different screen size.

`drawable-mdpi` will work for all your MDPI devices like normal phone,7' & 10' tablet.

you need to use different drawable for few images like your app background which wont fit for all screen sizes.

```
normal 320x480
7'     1024 x 600
10'   1280 x 800
```

**Note:** 5' inch screen size won't come in `drawable-large-mdpi` bucket

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly : use only `drawable-mdpi`  folder and you will not have any problem!